# Getting property named `foo`

Tags: python, properties

I have

```
class A:

    foo = 'f'
    baa = 'b'

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.foo

    @property
    def baa(self):
        return self.baa
```

I want to make this procedure:

```
get(myclass, prop):
```

which gets the property of the class.
For example `a = A()` and `get(a, 'foo')` gives me `f`. And `a = 2` and `gets(a, 'imag')` gives me `0`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear whether you need to read an introductory book on python oop, you are trying to do something elaborate which you did not tell us about, or whether this is a heavy XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @MaxNoe, the method you want is `getattr()`. However, you could create an alias for it, if you want to just use `get()` instead. Also works for class instances, obviously.

```
#accepts class name (c) and attribute (attr)
def get(c,attr):
    #returns the attribute
    return getattr(c,attr)
```

### Flask usage (obligatory?)

```
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def get(c,attr):
    return getattr(c,attr)
```

Comment: How to use it in flask?

Comment: `get = getattr` would create an alias without having to define a new function.

Comment: I get `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'getattr' is undefined` with `{{getattr(r,f)}}` in my template. (f is str and r is class)

Answer (score 3):

The build-in is called `getattr`.

Also you need to call the property and the variable differently:

You cannot access a property with `getattr`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 'f'
        self._bar = 'b'

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

a = A()
print(a.foo)
print(getattr(a, '_foo'))
```